# Problem in computing Dsolve

Tags: differential-equations

I want to compute my result using Dsolve. The code is given below.

```
Remove["Global`*"];
e = 1.6*10^-19;
h = 6.63*10^-34;
phi = 1.4*1.6*10^-19;
s = 1.8*10^-9;
m = 9.11*10^-31;
beta = 23/24;
A = 3*10^-4;
pi = 3.14;
a= (e/(2*3.14*h*s^2));
b = -(4*pi*s/h);
c = Sqrt[(2*m*(phi - (e*vk)/2))];
d = Sqrt[(2*m*(phi + (e*vk)/2))];
f = e^3/(4*pi*h*phi*s^2*beta^2);
g = -4*pi*beta/e/h*Sqrt[m]*phi^(3/2);
eps0 = 8.85*10^-12;
k1 = 100;
k2 = 20;
dt = 5*10^-9;
r = 1;
fre = 1000000;
v0 = 8.7;
T = 2*(1/fre);
v[t] = v0*Sin[2*Pi*fre*t];

ListPlot[Table[{t, %}, {t, 0, T, T/(1000 + 1)}]]

c0 = (A*eps0*k1)/dt;
cap = c0/(1 + (((s*q1[t])/(dt*q[t]))));
eQ = (q[t] + q1[t])/(2*A*eps0*k2);
vk = eQ*s;
J1 = Sqrt[(2*m*phi)]/s*(e/h)^2*vk*E^(b*Sqrt[(2*m*phi)]);
J2 = a*((phi - (e*vk)/2)*E^(b*c) - (phi + (e*vk)/2)*E^(b*d));
J3 = f*(E^(g*s/vk) - (1 + (2*e*vk)/phi)*
  E^(g*s*Sqrt[(1 + (2*e*vk)/phi)]/vk))*vk^2;

I1 = J1*A;
I2 = J2*A;
I3 = J3*A;

z = I1 + I2 + I3;

qq = DSolve[{q'[t] == v[t]/r - q[t]/r*(1/cap), q1'[t] == J3*A, 
q[0] == 0, q1[0] == 0}, {q, q1}, t];

Rationalize@ComplexExpand[q[t] /. qq];
Plot[%, {t, 0, T}]
Rationalize@ComplexExpand[q1[t] /. qq];
Plot[%, {t, 0, T}]
```

**My Goal :**

- To compute `DSolve` while using `q1'[t] == J3*A`, and then `q1'[t] == J2*A` and then `q1'[t] == J1*A` separately. and then finally `q1'[t] == J3*A+J2*A+J1*A`

**Issue:**

- When I compute `DSolve` using `q1'[t] == J1*A`, it works fine. but for all other cases like `q1'[t] == J2*A` and `q1'[t] == J3*A` and the final one one `q1'[t] == J3*A+J2*A+J1*A`, either it takes much time and it never give me the result or it gives me so many error that I am unable to debug it.

Comment: Can you reduce your question to its absolute minimum core elements?  Who wants to slog through all your definitions and such to find (and perhaps answer) the core problem you face?

Comment: It seems that the error occurred because `DSolve` can't solve your ODE with `J2` and `J3`

Comment: It cannot work for 2 reasons  i) your equations are singular at the initial conditions ii) mathematica does not know how to solve such equation symbolically.

Comment: @chris..If my equations are singular. Then is there any way to solve it ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First, with expressions like these

```
E^(-(0.00121935/(q[t] + q1[t]))) ... E^(-((0.00121935 Sqrt[1 + 24213.1 (q[t] + q1[t])])
```

it's unlikely that the ODE can be integrated exactly, as has been pointed out in comments.

Second, using approximate coefficients (instead of exact rational, algebraic, or transcendental numbers) is going to make  rather difficult doing the sort of exact analysis that `DSolve` tries to carry out.  Given the first remark, this is a minor concern here.  One can convert the approximate numbers to rational numbers with `Rationalize[expr, 0]`, which helps in some cases but not this one.

If a numerical approximation is acceptable -- the system has no symbolic parameters, so maybe it is -- we can try to use `NDSolve`.  There are two issues, one algebraic and one numerical.  Given the difficulty of the numerical issue, one should consider if there is a better initial condition than `q[0] == 0, q1[0] == 0`.

The algebraic one is easy.  The expressions for the derivatives of `q` and `q1` have `q` and `q1` in the denominator, so that the initial condition `q[0] == 0, q1[0] == 0` leads to undefined `q'[0], q1'[0]`.  But this is not a true singularity since the limits of the expressions are finite.  For `q'[t]`, we can just multiply out the right-hand side and the denominators cancel out.  For `q1'[t]`, we can use `Piecewise` to give the appropriate value at `q == q1 == 0`.

The numerical problem is difficult. First, realize that machine precision computations work well only in a certain range of values.  (For instance `1 + $MachineEpsilon/2` is identical to `1.`. A glance at the coefficients show a large range of exponents, which might contribute or not; I did not look into it, but the OP can if desired.  The exponential terms vanish exceedingly fast at `q == q1 == 0`, which might lead to underflow and round-off errors.  And so on.)  While there is a certain approximate similarity to most of the computed approximate solutions, the system appears to be numerically unstable.

```
dq1 = Piecewise[
       {{Limit[J3*A /. q[t] + q1[t] -> x, x -> 0], q[t] == 0 && q1[t] == 0}},
       J3*A];
wp = MachinePrecision;
sol = $Failed;
{sol} = NDSolve[
  SetPrecision[
   {q'[t] == Expand[v[t]/r - q[t]/r*(1/cap)], 
    q1'[t] == dq1, q[0] == 0, q1[0] == 0},
   wp],
  {q, q1}, {t, 0, 1},
  MaxSteps -> 100000, WorkingPrecision -> wp];

If[FreeQ[sol, NDSolve | $Failed],
 Module[{qscale, q1scale},
  qscale =
   10^-Floor@Log10[Max[Abs[q["ValuesOnGrid"] /. sol][[;; -3]]] /. x_ /; x == 0 -> 1];
  q1scale = 
   10^-Floor@Log10[Max[Abs[q1["ValuesOnGrid"] /. sol][[;; -3]]] /. x_ /; x == 0 -> 1];
  Plot @@ {{qscaleq[t], q1scale q1[t]} /. sol,
    Flatten[{t, q["Domain"] /. sol}], 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{N@qscale, "q, ", N@q1scale "q1;", " wp" -> wp}]}
  ]]
```

We can change the working precision `wp`.  The functions `q`, `q1` are plotted with individual scales. These are noted in the plot labels.  Note: (1) The scaling factors for `q1`; (2) `wp = 12` gives a constant `0` solution (so does `wp = 16`) -- I did not look into why; (3) integration fails at different points, as can be seen in the domains of the plots; (4) at `wp =20`, I get the message `General::nomem`, insufficient memory.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]